# Print Bootstrap Grid Layout using Custom Styling

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was working with Bootstrap Grid and made a Layout. I want to print exactly the same that is displaying on the Web Page, same layout No change. I try to use some sort of print method using javascript for adding custom CSS codes but all in vain.

Here is my sample layout ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arslanahmedawan/x789ofnt/)) that I want to print exactly the same.

The last print JavaScript code that I tried was:

```
<script>
var all_source_content = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
var DocumentContainer = document.getElementById('main_container');
var WindowObject = window.open('', 'PrintWindow', '');
WindowObject.document.writeln('<!DOCTYPE html>');
WindowObject.document.writeln('<html><head><title></title>');
WindowObject.document.writeln('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">');
WindowObject.document.writeln('<style></style>');
WindowObject.document.writeln('</head><body>');
console.log(DocumentContainer.innerHTML);
WindowObject.document.writeln(DocumentContainer.innerHTML);
WindowObject.document.writeln('</body></html>');
WindowObject.document.close();
WindowObject.focus();
WindowObject.print();
</script>
```

But it also did not help me.

My desired layout:

[image]

Comment: what are u trying to do  if u want to print the web page then just copy the content and paste it inside the print function

Comment: By doing it is not printing exactly the same layout.

Comment: now what r u trying just u want to print the whole content using print method y u have created  windowobject ?

Comment: Sir, Someone told me that I have to write inline styling for it But instead of inline style I added the reference stylesheet link of bootstrap. Sir, I just want to print exactly the same layout that is showing on the Web Page. Kindly Help If you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are creating a new window If the window couldn't be opened, it returns a null value.

if u r using chrome browser check u r console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of null
>   u can see this error.

This is because of browser's default settings the pop-ups are blocked by default. if you want u can change the option to allow.

Then if you want to print the page as it is you have to **adjust the scale factor while printing**.
[image]

Comment: This is not the issue Sir.
If you will try to Print it using Ctrl+P, Then it will not print in my desired format/layout.

Comment: so u want to print into a single page while printing i'm right ? @JohnDoe

Comment: I already accepted it yesterday but i dont know why its un-accepted again. I accepted it again.